# Silverlight app disabled when out of browser

Tags: silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

I have a silverlight 5 app that runs fine in browser but as soon as I run it out of browser it does a number of things on start-up (like login screen etc) but then it gets grayed out (as if the background rectangle of a child window has not closed) and it remains that way. I cannot imagine that this is a SL issue but cannot find anything in our app that could cause this, has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: This actually seems to be related to checking for an update on the server using App.Current.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync(), any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you correctly configured the app as a desktop application?

**msdn.microsoft.com**

- [How to: Configure an Application for Out-of-Browser Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833073%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Building An Out-of-Browser Client With Silverlight 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882515.aspx) - different version but might be helpful.

**silverlightshow.net**

- [Silverlight as a Desktop Application (Out-of-Browser Applications)](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-as-a-Desktop-Application-Out-of-Browser-Applications.aspx)
- [How to distribute a Silverlight OOB Application?](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/How-to-distribute-a-Silverlight-OOB-Application.aspx) - Specifically the "Configuring OOB Settings" section.

Comment: I have, and I have also tried different combinations of settings. If I remove the code that looks for an update then it works fine, as soon as it checks the server for an answer it locks up.